# Search and return data from worksheet into userform on a secondary worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a search command that is working as long as I activate it from the worksheet with the data,(run it from the visual basic) but the command button is in a separate worksheet to the data and I am unable to get it to return the data to the userform when not in visual basic. The command button is in the "STOCK" worksheet and the data in "StockData"

I have looked at a lot of search or find codes but all work in the current sheet and in this manner mine also works. Struggling to understand how to get the code to read from one sheet and return to another sheet into the userform

```
Private Sub cmdFindR_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
Dim wStock As Worksheet
Set wStock = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData")
With wStock
totalrow = wStock.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
    If Trim(txtRecLine.Text) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 1)) Then
        txtTransactionCd.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)
        txtTrip.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
        txtDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5)
 End If
Next currentrow
End With
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
currentrow = 2
End Sub
```

[image]

I look forward to getting this right, hope someone can help. I am sure it is not too hard but this is my first database and I'm loving the learning, but struggling here and there.

Thank you,T

Comment: There are unqualified references `Cells(...)...` within the `For currentrow ... Next` loop, which actually refers to active worksheet if used such way. Even though you already created `With ... End With` statement; use it, refer to the cells of the `wStock` worksheet, to do so you need just to add dots right before `Cells(...)...` -> `.Cells(...)...`

Comment: Thank you. I am learning a lot and its the small things that are most useful.